Forcing browsers to recheck the `:active` state?


div:active {
  color: red;
}
<div>test</div>



In this trivial example, on Chrome, the element can be stuck in the :active state. Here's a video: https://i.imgur.com/6GeQJlM.mp4
Even though my mouse has left the element, Chrome is still applying :active to it.
On desktop Chrome, it's not a big deal, since :active styles get removed after I interact with the page. However, on Android Chrome, the :active style can persist until I refresh the page. I noticed that this issue often occurs when I switch apps right after tapping an element with :active. My hypothesis is that after switching back to Chrome, Chrome doesn't check that the element is no longer in the :active state.
Is there a way to force browsers to recheck the :active state for every element? I'd do this when switching back to my web app, i.e. using visibilitychange.
I tried adding and removing display: none, document.activeElement.blur(), calling focus() on another element, adding tabindex, etc. The only thing that worked was removing and adding back the style, but that seems error-prone.

This seems like an X/Y issue. What is the real problem that having the :active state stay with the element is causing you?

The real problem is having the :active style always there?

Right, and other than potentially raising a bug with the Chrome (which can be done here) is this having an effect on any development you're doing? I'm asking so that we might be able to help you find a workaround.

Here's context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78851295/css-gets-stuck-in-the-active-state

Seems like this bug has already been reported: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/358393574

The :active pseudo-class is commonly used on <a> and <button> elements - from the docs.

These are all irrelevant to the question, the question is "Is there a way to force browsers to recheck the :active state for every element?"
